# Where does a Collection View Flow Layout fit in MVC?

Tags: objective-c, paradigms

I'm putting together a flow layout and I'm trying to conform to MVC as closely as possible. I'm confused where UICollectionViewFlowLayout falls into. The closest of the three buckets would be view, but a layout is not a view either.

Where does the layout fit?

Comment: In my opinion it's controller, as it controls the layout of the view.

Comment: There are more things in heaven and earth, Moshe, 
than are dreamt of in your MVC philosophy.